# How could a flex UI processing data and displaydata in one thread

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

As I know. Flex/AS is single threaded.

I want to write an application that talking to server side, also display the data streamed from server.

Since Flex is single threaded. I am not sure how could I do this.

Better not involve something like "implement your own multi-thread model"

Thanks

Comment: Can you shed a few more details , as to how you are interactin with the server? HttpService object perhaps??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to talk to a server and handle the displaying at the *same* time.
Communication (HTTPRequest, webServices, RemoteObject/AMF,...) is asynchronous, non-blocking.
You can't update the screen at the same time that you're *starting* a request, but you can while you're waiting for the answer.